# Java Calculator Assistance

Tags: java, calculator

This is my 1st post here and I am hoping if I could get some help on a school project I have. The project is to make a calculator in Java and I have made it and it works fine for the most part, only problem I am having is that when I get an answer - lets say `5+5=10` and 10 is displayed, when I want to enter another number lets say I want to enter in 8*10 and in order to do that I write in 8, instead of deleting the previous answer  which is 10 and write 8 instead of that number it will write 8 after 10, so it will be 108. What I want is for the previous answer to be deleted once I enter in a new number after an answer has been give. I hope I explained it good, here is my code and I would love some assistance on the matter since everything I tried hasn't worked. Thanks in advance.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Calculator_UI implements ActionListener {

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Calculator");
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(1, 20);
    JButton but1 = new JButton("1");
    JButton but2 = new JButton("2");
    JButton but3 = new JButton("3");
    JButton but4 = new JButton("4");
    JButton but5 = new JButton("5");
    JButton but6 = new JButton("6");
    JButton but7 = new JButton("7");
    JButton but8 = new JButton("8");
    JButton but9 = new JButton("9");
    JButton but0 = new JButton("0");
    JButton butadd = new JButton("+");
    JButton butsub = new JButton("-");
    JButton butmulti = new JButton("*");
    JButton butdiv = new JButton("/");
    JButton buteq = new JButton("=");
    JButton butclear = new JButton("C");
    Double number1, number2, result;
    int addc = 0, subc = 0, multic = 0, divc = 0;

    public void ui() {
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(230, 200);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(panel);

        panel.add(text);
        panel.add(but1);
        panel.add(but2);
        panel.add(but3);
        panel.add(but4);
        panel.add(but5);
        panel.add(but6);
        panel.add(but7);
        panel.add(but8);
        panel.add(but9);
        panel.add(but0);

        panel.add(butadd);
        panel.add(butsub);
        panel.add(butmulti);
        panel.add(butdiv);
        panel.add(buteq);
        panel.add(butclear);

        but1.addActionListener(this);
        but1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but2.addActionListener(this);
        but2.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but3.addActionListener(this);
        but3.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but4.addActionListener(this);
        but4.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but5.addActionListener(this);
        but5.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but6.addActionListener(this);
        but6.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but7.addActionListener(this);
        but7.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but8.addActionListener(this);
        but8.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but9.addActionListener(this);
        but9.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        but0.addActionListener(this);
        but0.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        butadd.addActionListener(this);
        butadd.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butsub.addActionListener(this);
        butsub.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butmulti.addActionListener(this);
        butmulti.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butdiv.addActionListener(this);
        butdiv.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        buteq.addActionListener(this);
        buteq.setBackground(Color.cyan);
        butclear.addActionListener(this);
        butclear.setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();

        if (source == butclear) {
            number1 = 0.0;
            number2 = 0.0;
            text.setText("");
        }

        if (source == but1) {
            text.append("1");
        }
        if (source == but2) {
            text.append("2");
        }
        if (source == but3) {
            text.append("3");
        }
        if (source == but4) {
            text.append("4");
        }
        if (source == but5) {
            text.append("5");
        }
        if (source == but6) {
            text.append("6");
        }
        if (source == but7) {
            text.append("7");
        }
        if (source == but8) {
            text.append("8");
        }
        if (source == but9) {
            text.append("9");
        }
        if (source == but0) {
            text.append("0");
        }
        if (source == butadd) {
            number1 = number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc = 1;
            subc = 0;
            multic = 0;
            divc = 0;
        }
        if (source == butsub) {
            number1 = number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc = 0;
            subc = 1;
            multic = 0;
            divc = 0;
        }
        if (source == butmulti) {
            number1 = number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc = 0;
            subc = 0;
            multic = 1;
            divc = 0;
        }
        if (source == butdiv) {
            number1 = number_reader();
            text.setText("");
            addc = 0;
            subc = 0;
            multic = 0;
            divc = 1;
        }

        if (source == buteq) {
            number2 = number_reader();
            if (addc == 1) {
                result = number1 + number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }
            if (subc == 1) {
                result = number1 - number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }
            if (multic == 1) {
                result = number1 * number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));

            }
            if (divc == 1) {
                result = number1 / number2;
                text.setText(Double.toString(result));
            }
        }
    }

    public double number_reader() {
        Double num1;
        String s;
        s = text.getText();
        num1 = Double.valueOf(s);

        return num1;
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldn't really be posting in here for homework. have you tried using trusty google?

Comment: Ofc I have, I know its homework but after asking my classmates and not finding an answer on google this is my last resort, I don't like to "cheat" But my program works anyways, its just not 100% perfect, I will probably be graded a 10/10 but I want to know how I can fix this problem so I can learn something from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the user presses `=` and the result is printed, you should set a flag to true, so that the next time a number button is pressed, the result is first erased.

In fact you should even transform your whole logic into a [state diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram), because if, for example, the user presses `+` twice, you should probably display an error message or ignore the second `+`, instead of reading the current number. Each state should define what happens when any button is pressed, and what the next state is depending on which button is pressed.

Since a GUI can be smarter than a real calculator, each state could also define which buttons are enabled and which ones are disabled.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I haven't even tought of editing the =, I was constantly trying to edit the buttons for some odd reason, thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)